# Get the current task being run when Laravel queue:listen times out

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, queue, supervisord

We are running Laravel 4 with supervisord / SQS and we have 30+ different tasks being run using 10 worker processes. All has been going very well however it seems that certain tasks have started to timeout. We get an exception like this:

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException]
The process ""/usr/bin/php5" artisan queue:work  --queue="https://sqs.us-east-     1.amazonaws.com/xxxx" --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=0 --env=development" exceeded the timeout of 180 seconds.
```

I can catch this exception using this:

```
App::error(function(Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException $exception) {

    /// caught!
});
```

However I can't seem to determine WHICH task is being run (when the timeout occurs) and even better if I can access the data which was passed to the task..

I have tried logging the exception object stack trace:

```
$exception->getTraceAsString()
```

However, this doesn't get me enough detail about the task that was called.

**UPDATE**

I have done more research on how the `php artisan queue:listen` works. Some references:

- [Illuminate/Queue/Console/Listen](https://github.com/illuminate/queue/blob/46e24cdf8bd4b95f34d6d356aaece5b5b814577b/Console/ListenCommand.php)
- [Illuminate/Queue/Listener](https://github.com/illuminate/queue/blob/714fb2a16fa9c456fe1b7577394111ea7a0f6c8c/Listener.php)
- [Symfony/Component/Process](https://github.com/symfony/Process/blob/master/Process.php)

Basically, when you call `php artisan queue:listen`, a SUB-PROCESS (using Symfony/Component/Process) is created which essentially runs the command `php artisan queue:work`. That sub-process fetches the next job from the queue, runs it, reports when complete, and then the Listener spawns another sub-process to handle the next job.

So, if one of the sub-processes is taking longer than the established timeout limit, the PARENT Listener throws an exception however, the parent instance has no data about the sub-process it created. WITH A SLIGHT EXCEPTION! It appears that the parent Listener DOES handle the sub-process' output. It appears to me that the parent does nothing more than render the sub-process' (worker) output to the console. However, perhaps there is a way to capture this output so that when an exception is thrown, we can log the output and therefore have knowledge about which task was running when the timeout occurred!

I have also noticed that when using supervisord, we are able to specify a `stdout_logfile` which logs all of the worker output. Right now we are using a single log file for all of our 10 supervisord "programs". We could change this to have each "program" use it's own log file and then perhaps when the timeout exception is thrown on the parent Listener, we could have it grab the last 10 lines of that log file. That would also give us info on which tasks are being run during the timeout. However, I am not sure how to "inform" the parent Listener which supervisord program it is running so it knows which log file to look at!

Comment: If it happens often enough - and for a quick debug - you could just log "Task X starting" and "Task X finished". Then when the timeout occurs - see which task had not finished...

Comment: @TheShiftExchange unfortunately that doesn't help much. Very often the timeout occurs but the job still completes and still logs the "Task X finished" message.

Comment: Actually - doesnt that tell us alot? That's why you cannot catch the task that was called - because the task is complete? So the problem lies outside of the task?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange you could be right. But I am also worried this is a Laravel artisan:listen problem. It might be that the `listen` command is spawning a new process `queue:work` and is not ending the process when the timeout is reached. Same reason why I cannot determine which task is being run by the timeout exception being thrown in the `listen` command. I have to do more digging into Laravel source code to be sure. Either way I have a larger architecture issue to deal with ;)

Comment: Something like this might help tracking all your tasks/queues/crons: eyewitness.io (disclaimer: this is my site).

Comment: Thanks @TheShiftExchange -- your service looks interesting. Hopefully it is going well. I just added some more clarification based on my digging into the Laravel and Symfony source.

Comment: Does `$exception->getProcess()` hold any information that would help?

Comment: @lukasgeiter -- actually yes! `$exception->getProcess()->getOutput()` is returning the output from the worker process. A few initial tests are working out. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Great! I will run some tests on my own and write up a (hopefully) helpful answer :)

Comment: @lukasgeiter -- it's not super elegant, as I need to actually `echo()` the output from each task. I am echoing `get_class()` and `json_encode($task_data)` from the top of each task. Going to move this into a parent `BaseTask` class I suppose. Do you know if there is way to write to output without using `echo()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the exception class (`Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException`) I found the method `getProcess()` which returns an instance of `Symfony\Component\Process\Process`. In there you got `getOutput()`. The method does what it's name says.

As you proposed in the comments you can use this by echoing classname and parameters in each task and then using the generated output to determine the problematic task. As you said, it's not very elegant but I can't think of a better way (except maybe tinkering with the `Illuminate\Queue\Listener` class...)

Here's an example how you could do it (untested though)

I chose this format for the output:

```
ClassName:ParametersAsJson;ClassName:ParametersAsJson;
```

So in a BaseTask I'd do this:

```
abstract class BaseTask {
    public function fire(){
        echo get_class($this) . ':' . json_encode(func_get_args()) . ';';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately that means in every task you will have to call `parent::fire`

```
class Task extends BaseTask {
    public function fire($param1, $param2){
        parent::fire($param1, $param2);

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And finally, the exception handler:

```
App::error(function(Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException $exception) {

    $output = $exception->getProcess()->getOutput();
    $tasks = explode(';', $output);
    array_pop($output); // remove empty task that's here because of the closing ";"
    $lastTask = end($tasks);
    $parts = explode(':', $lastTask);

    $className = $parts[0];
    $parameters = json_decode($parts[1]);

    // write details to log

});
```

Comment: I already did it almost exactly as you have proposed. Waiting for timeouts to happen now in production. Will post results! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since Laravel 4.1 there is a built-in mechanism for handling failed jobs where all job details are persisted in database or available at exception-time (or both). Detailed and clear documentation is available on [Laravel's website](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#failed-jobs).

**To summarise:**

1. Laravel can move failed jobs into a `failed_jobs` table for later review
2. You can register an exception handler via `Queue::failing`, which will receive detailed job information for immediate handling

However, it is questionable whether a timeout is considered a failure in Laravel, so this requires testing as I do not have hands-on experience with queues.

If you use Laravel 4.0 perhaps it would be worthwhile to evaluate an upgrade at least to 4.1 instead of writing complicated code that will become redundant once you really have to upgrade (you **will** upgrade at some point, right? :) ). [Upgrade path](http://laravel.com/docs/4.1/upgrade#upgrade-4.1) seems quite straightforward.

While this does not directly answer your question for Laravel 4.0 it is something you and any future reader may consider.

Comment: This is a really good answer and is also native to Laravel. I have accepted the other answer because it allows me to also capture the output of the specific task which failed (caused the timeout) to help with debugging the cause of the timeout. I can do benchmarking, for example, and then capture that output in my logged error message.